# How to retrieve an array from within a document that matches a certain ID?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor

I am building an application in Meteor, and I want to retrieve the array of images from a Mongo collection where testKey = 1. The result being that I would have a Javascript variable that holds an array that looks like:

`["filepath-here", "filepath2-here",...}`

Example Mongo collection:

```
{
  "testKey": 1,
  "images": [
    "filepath-here",
    "filepath2-here",
  ]
}
```

I have tried this:

```
var testImgCount = Tests.find( { testKey : randomTest }, { fields: { 'images': 1, '_id':0 }}).fetch();
```

When I console.log it returns [Object], and when I open that up it shows

`[0: object, length: 1, _proto_: Array[0]`

`0: object` in this instance holds the array that I am trying to get access to. How can I go about this to only return this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution.

```
var testImgCount = Tests.findOne( { testKey : randomTest } ).images;
```

This code successfully returned only the array of images that I was looking for. I'll mark this as answered and hopefully this can help someone else in the future.